# Need Assistance Updating an IF/THEN Statement

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have this calculated column formula for stoplights on my SharePoint list and I need just a little help updating/tweaking this particular formula.  IF/THEN statements are not my forte.

```
=IF(OR([Date Needed]<Today,Date+90<Today),"red",IF(OR(Modified+15<Today,Status="project"),"yellow","green"))
```

The addition or change to this formula is the addition of Status="closed" turns the stoplight to green.

Thank you,

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact requirement of your calculated field.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=IF(Status="closed","green",IF(OR([Date Needed]<Today,Date+90<Today),"red",IF(OR(Modified+15<Today,Status="project"),"yellow","green")))
```

**UPDATE**

```
=IF(OR(Status="closed",Status="cancelled"),"green",IF(OR([Date Needed]<Today,Date+90<Today),"red",IF(OR(Modified+15<Today,Status="project"),"yellow","green")))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly...although now a new last minute requirement is to make cancelled green as well.  Would this be the correct addition to the formula 

=IF(Status="closed,cancelled","green",IF(OR([Date Needed]<Today,Date+90<Today),"red",IF(OR(Modified+15<Today,Status="project"),"yellow","green")))

Comment: @ChrisL no this won't work..

Comment: @ChrisL I've updated the answer to include cancelled status as well